# Diffence between .SSHTML and .SHTML extension

Tags: html, shtml

Can some share the difference between .shtml and .sshtml extension? Are they the same or different?

Answer (score 1):

`.shtml` is the traditional file extension for HTML documents containing [Server Side Include](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) directives.

`.sshtml` is the traditional file extension for [The Super Simple View Engine](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-Super-Simple-View-Engine) (which is no longer being maintained).

They are unrelated.